# Axiom of choice Nested sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we consider the family of sets $A_n = [-1/n,1/n] $ minus the point 0 , its clear that the sets contain one another in a decreasing order. by the axiom of choice we can choose an element of each set and since the sets are nested we can choose that element to be the same element, so the element will belong to the intersection of the $A_n$ which is empty contradicting the existing of such an element !!

Excuse my English and math typing

Comment: "since the sets are nested we can choose that element to be the same element" -- Only if their intersection is nonempty. Which it isn't, since you removed 0. But in general AC only says a choice set exists, you can't choose its members. If you have a way to choose the members then you don't need AC!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the axiom of choice says "It is possible to select an element from each set", it doesn't say "This is the way you can select an element of each set". So in particular, you're trying to construct a selection method that is "pick the element from each set that is in the intersection of all the sets", which as you yourself demonstrate is impossible because their intersection is empty.